# Gradle refers jars but they are not in POM nor in the code links

Tags: gradle

We migrated our maven code to gradle. When we build, we are getting error as Could not resolve all files for configuration ':***-war:compileClasspath'.

> Could not find mockito-core.jar (org.mockito:mockito-core:2.8.9).

We are not referring to this jar itself.. neither we are able to locate in our code nor in pom...

How to figure out? 
how to configure gradle to compile code if jar doesn't exist and pom exists in the repository or locally ?

Comment: Check whether _mockito-core_ appears in the list of dependencies generated by `gradle dependencies`. You could also try running `gradle dependencyInsight --dependency mockito-core --configuration compileClasspath` which should identify where the dependency is coming from.

Comment: Thanks Peter. We tried suggested changes it doesn't help.

Comment: So mockito-core isn't in either dependency report?

Comment: No, it wasn't there.  To resolve the issue I have added mockito-core with lower of version as : compile group: 'org.mockito', name:'mockito-core', version:'1.10.19' as it was looking for 2.8.9....and 2.8.9 artifactory link has only pom files & it was failing..

Answer (score 1):

If you can't work out where it's coming from and you don't use it at all, then you can exclude the dependency from all the configurations:

```
configurations.all*.exclude group: "org.mockito", module: "mockito-core"
```

If the dependency isn't appearing in the dependency report, then I'm somewhat at a loss as to why Gradle is complaining about it. The only other option I can think of is that some plugin is adding it in a non-standard way.